Is there a way to get account's login email in telethon?
I can not find a api to get account's login email, is there a way to get account's login email?
I can not find a api about it in telethon.
I've tried to find a lot of APIs, but none of them have anything like this.
If anyone knows please tell me, thanks a lot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can't retrieve the full email address using any Telegram app or library, including the official app. However, you can access the pattern of the email address (e.g., email******123.com). To get this email pattern, you can use the GetPasswordRequest method in Telethon. Here’s an example code snippet from the Telegram documentation:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.account.GetPasswordRequest())
    print(result.stringify())

This code returns an account.Password object, which contains the login_email_pattern attribute if an email pattern is available.
